How to revoke symmetric key access to decrypt column in SQL Server
In SQL Server 2022, I am adding a decrypted column in my database, as per https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-the-column-level-sql-server-encryption/
Extra user was created using:
USE [master]
CREATE LOGIN [SQLShack] WITH PASSWORD=N'sqlshack', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[AdventureWorks2022], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
USE [AdventureWorks2022]
CREATE USER [SQLShack] FOR LOGIN [SQLShack]
USE [AdventureWorks2022]
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [SQLShack]

I followed suggestion to grant access to use a certificate to decode the column with:
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SYMMETRIC KEY::SymKey_test TO SQLShack; 
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON Certificate::[Certificate_test] TO SQLShack;
GRANT CONTROL ON Certificate::[Certificate_test] TO SQLShack;

But now I want to revoke access to the certificate with:
revoke control on symmetric key::SymKey_test TO SQLShack
revoke control ON Certificate::[Certificate_test] TO SQLShack;

But when I logon as SQLShack, I still have access to the certificate to decrypt my column. What is the correct call to remove access to use the certificate to decode an encrypted column.
For ease, this is the entire code:
USE AdventureWorks2022

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'SQLShack@1';
CREATE CERTIFICATE Certificate_test WITH SUBJECT = 'Protect my data';
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test;

-- encode using symmetric keys
SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2022.HumanResources.Employee

ALTER TABLE AdventureWorks2022.HumanResources.Employee
ADD BankACCNumber_encrypt varbinary(MAX)

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test;


UPDATE AdventureWorks2022.HumanResources.Employee
SET BankACCNumber_encrypt = EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymKey_test'), NationalIDNumber)
FROM AdventureWorks2022.HumanResources.Employee;
GO

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test;
GO

-- decode

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test;

SELECT 
    nationalIDNumber, BankACCNumber_encrypt AS 'Encrypted data',
    CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(BankACCNumber_encrypt)) AS 'Decrypted Bank account number'
FROM 
    AdventureWorks2022.HumanResources.Employee


What database role is SQLShack in? Side note: CONVERT(nvarchar, should use a length.

updated code to show how
